# There is a problem with the server configuration. Check the server logs for more information

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I used google as an auth provider with next auth. Configured all the the environment variables both in production and development. It's working perfectly in dev mode but in production it shows this error whenever i try to sign in.

I deployed the site to vercel and had setup google id, secret and NEXTAUTH_URL variables there.

I tried to setup google secret properly add it into vercel setting and google credential too

Comment: Have you "Check[ed] the server logs for more information"? If so, what does it say. If not, can you?

Answer (score 1):

just make sure that you have setup the secret enviroment variable in nextauth i.e
secret : process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET

Answer (score 0):

For Nextjs, add this

```
http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/google
```

in **Authorized redirect URIs** section